# How to add reference to new version of infragistics in .net windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I have add new infragistics references version 13.1 to my references by using utility and so when i add references with new version than an error comes with only one dll which is ultratabcontrol.dll. And the error comes

> Error 11  The type
>   'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTabSharedControlsPage' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinTabControl.v11.2,
>   Version=11.2.20112.1010, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'. E:\Projects\R-Suite\Communication\Forms\frmAddressBook.designer.cs  44  13  Communication

it is still finding references of the old version of ultratabcontol but other dll did'nt give any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've referenced the old version dll remove it from the references.
Than click add reference and find the same dll but with the right version and add it. Then rebuilt.
If you cannot find it just go to browse and find it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you have managed to be in this predicament. But usually, when you install a new version of the Netadvantage suite, you  will find, in your Visual Studio Toolbox, a new Group of tools for the current version just installed. THe previous version is still there because, to remove it, you need to deinstall. This is not done automatically for a good reason. You could decide to not upgrade your projects to the new version for any valid reason (lack of time, need to test and so on)

In this scenario it is possibile that you have choosen a component from the Group of the previous version. You should remove it or apply again the Upgrade Utility and then choose the appropriate group.

Instead if you have some problem with the Toolbox (Lacks the current version, want to remove the old one) you could find the utility `ToolboxUtilityCommandLine.exe` in the `C:\program files (x86)\Infragistcs\NetAdvantage<yourversion>Windows Forms\Toolbox Utility`. Look at the `Documentation.htm` to explore your options to deinstall or reinstall the appropriate toolbox.